# Does this expectation inequality holds?

Tags: self-study, expected-value, probability-inequalities, inequality

Let $X\in L_p(P), p>1$. Is the following result true? 
$$E[\lvert X\rvert I(\lvert X\rvert>C)]\leq C^{1-p}E\lvert X\rvert^p.$$
where $C>0$.

It can be found in the proof of Corollary A.1 (pp. 278) of [Hall & Heyde](http://www.stat.yale.edu/~mjk56/MartingaleLimitTheoryAndItsApplication.pdf)'s book.

My attempt

By Markov's inequality, $E[I(\lvert X\rvert>C)]=P(\lvert X\rvert>C)\leq C^{-p}E\lvert X\rvert^p$. But $\lvert X\rvert I(\lvert X\rvert>C)> CI(\lvert X\rvert>C)$, and I can't use Markov's result to bound $E[\lvert X\rvert I(\lvert X\rvert>C)]$. How to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

From Holder's and Markov's inequalities

$$E(\lvert X \rvert I(\lvert X \rvert>C))\leq \lVert X\rVert_p (P(\lvert X\rvert>C))^{1-1/p}\leq \lVert X\rVert_p [E(\lvert X \rvert^p/C^p)]^{1-1/p}=E\lvert X \rvert^pC^{1-p}$$
the desired result. The powers confused me a bit...